# Plot number of elapsed days in x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot the number of days elapsed in the x-axis, instead of the month-year etc.
I've tried a few things without luck.

```
library(lubridate)
date <-  mdy_hm("10/23/02 12:00") + 60*(1:(60 * 24* 30))
value <- rnorm(length(date))
df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 value = value)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
  geom_line()
```

What desired is to have in the x-axis is something like `date - date[1]` with ticks in number of **days**.

Comment: Add days elapse and plot that? `df$dayselapse <-  as.numeric(difftime(df$date, min(df$date), units ="days"))

ggplot(data=df, aes(x = dayselapse, y = value)) +
  geom_line()`

Comment: Will this give what you want? `df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(date), 
         diffday = as.integer(Date - first(Date))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x = diffday, y = value) +
  geom_line()
`

Comment: I was after @user2738526's solutions. Thanks for both of you!